# Is there a way to share the subsite link again?

Tags: permissions, sub-site

I have moved a subsite to another location and would like to email all shared users a new url. Is it possible to "resend" the link to all current shared users as if they were just given permissions?

Answer (score 3):

On Sharepoint 2013/Online, when you hit on Share you will get the option to see who it's being shared with, right there you will see "send an email to everyone".

[image: Shared with>Email everyone]

Anytime you are asking it is necessary you let people know what version of Sharepoint you are running since the answer will vary based on the version.

If you want the same email sent by Microsoft, I can't help you with that.

Comment: I only see "Page Permissions" instead of share with. I am not going to add anyone and if I do add someone the only option is to email that user an invitation.

Comment: Added the screenshot for online version, anyhow, let know what version of sharepoint your environment is running to get the correct answers.